# Showing solutions graphically for N queens problem in java

Tags: java, user-interface, window, n-queens

I have the working code that you can see bellow, I just need someone to help me how to enable user to insert number of queens in a new window and then the program should show all solutions in a new window that will graphically show the chessboard and the queens.

```
Java program to solve N Queen   
Problem using backtracking

public class GfG  
{ 

static int N = 2;  
static int k = 1; 

/* A utility function to print solution */
static void printSolution(int board[][])  
{  
    System.out.printf("%d-\n", k++);  
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)  
    {  
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)  
            System.out.printf(" %d ", board[i][j]);  
        System.out.printf("\n");  
    }  
    System.out.printf("\n");  
}
```

A utility function to check if a queen can
be placed on board[row][col]. Note that this
function is called when "col" queens are
already placed in columns from 0 to col -1.
So we need to check only left side for
attacking queens

```
static boolean isSafe(int board[][], int row, int col)  
{  
    int i, j;  

    /* Check this row on left side */
    for (i = 0; i < col; i++)  
        if (board[row][i] == 1)  
            return false;  

    /* Check upper diagonal on left side */
    for (i = row, j = col; i >= 0 && j >= 0; i--, j--)  
        if (board[i][j] == 1)  
            return false;  

    /* Check lower diagonal on left side */
    for (i = row, j = col; j >= 0 && i < N; i++, j--)  
        if (board[i][j] == 1)  
            return false;  

    return true;  
}
```

A recursive utility function
to solve N Queen problem

```
static boolean solveNQUtil(int board[][], int col)  
{  
    /* base case: If all queens are placed  
    then return true */
    if (col == N)  
    {  
        printSolution(board);  
        return true;  
    }  

    /* Consider this column and try placing  
    this queen in all rows one by one */
    boolean res = false;  
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)  
    {  
        /* Check if queen can be placed on  
        board[i][col] */
        if ( isSafe(board, i, col) )  
        {  
            /* Place this queen in board[i][col] */
            board[i][col] = 1;  

            // Make result true if any placement  
            // is possible  
            res = solveNQUtil(board, col + 1) || res;  

            /* If placing queen in board[i][col]  
            doesn't lead to a solution, then  
            remove queen from board[i][col] */
            board[i][col] = 0; // BACKTRACK  
        }  
    }  

    /* If queen can not be place in any row in  
        this column col then return false */
    return res;  
}
```

This function solves the N Queen problem using
Backtracking. It mainly uses solveNQUtil() to
solve the problem. It returns false if queens
cannot be placed, otherwise return true and
prints placement of queens in the form of 1s.
Please note that there may be more than one
solutions, this function prints one of the
feasible solutions.

```
static void solveNQ()  
{  
    int board[][] = new int[N][N];  

    if (solveNQUtil(board, 0) == false)  
    {  
        System.out.printf("Solution does not exist");  
        return ;  
    }  

    return ;  
}  

// Driver code  
public static void main(String[] args) 
{ 
    solveNQ(); 
} 
}
```

Comment: Please show what you already have related to your UI. What are the problems you have to create a UI?

Comment: @zyexal here is my code for the board https://drive.google.com/open?id=1XWpRWd2HeIhWEFs3w6aoqsfDZsNsMoE5 But I dont know how to put the queens depending on the first code I posted here